# Unable to run cdk commands on my windows having python installed

Tags: aws-cdk

Installed aws-cdk using pip on windows10. After restart, when i run cdk --version on cmd prompt, it says 'cdk' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

aws --version
aws-cli/2.0.30 Python/3.7.7 Windows/10 botocore/2.0.0dev34

python --version
Python 3.8.1

Do I need to install NodeJS as well?

Please help me setup cdk on my windows10 laptop....

Comment: Do a search on this site for *not recognized as an internal or external command*, and read a couple of the hundreds of search results. It will give you information on what you should do to correct this problem. Always please search for the error message you're getting, as chances are that the same or similar question has been asked here before.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I didn't find anything specific and hence the post :)

Comment: it doesn't have to be specific. Any answer related to this question is applicable. The solution is the same regardless of what language or tool or utility you're using. If the solution is *add the directory your tool/utility/whatever to the system path*, it doesn't matter what the *tool/utility/whatever* is - the solution is the same. Read my previous comment again. We're not here to answer questions specific to your situation, but to offer solutions that tell you what you need to apply them to that situation.

Comment: To make it clear: if you want to add two integer variables, it makes no difference whether those variables are `x` and `y` or `a` and `b` - you're still adding two integer variables. There's no sense in having hundreds of posts here that are identical except for the name of something - the solution is the same.

Comment: @KenWhite....i hope the answer below is way less than what you spent on typing essay mate :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/getting_started.html) you need to have Node.js installed.

And I'll quote from the documentation

> All CDK developers need to install Node.js 10.3.0 or later, even those working in languages other than TypeScript or JavaScript.

Also..

> Install the AWS CDK Toolkit globally using the following Node Package Manager command.

```
npm install -g aws-cdk
```

After that you should be able to run `cdk --version` without any issues

Answer (score 0):

I have been driven into the same issue for using lower node version. If you have been install CDK in your computer previously and has been running CDK commands early.

Please check your local machine has newer Node version.
You can use NVM to manage node versions in your local machine.